# Firestore Stream closed with status UNAVAILABLE description Channel shutdownNow invoked

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am developing a flutter app. Before this error, reading and writing to the firestore database has no issues but then suddenly I am having error (shown below) and prevents me from reading or writing to the database. I have sought for answers but unfortunately I did not find any that will solve my problem.

Debug Console Output:

```
W/Firestore(27297): (24.1.2) [WriteStream]: (bbd84bb) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule(27297): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(27297): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(27297): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem. Also same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73345658/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-backend-didnt-respond-within-10-second This is a MAJOR BUG yet no one wants to fix it. I've resorted to using a physical android device for all development of flutter.

Comment: Same here, no flutter. Kotlin app. Anybody found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's DNS problem. using 1.1.1.1 warp VPN solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue. In my case, i also had cloud functions listening to a particular collection on firestore db. I was using wrong path which caused my channel to shutdown.

Valid path for listening to all documents in a collection via cloud functions

```
functions.firestore.document(`collectionId/{docId}`)
```

But i have used like,

```
functions.firestore.document(`collectionId/\${docId}`)
```

have added '$' before '{docId}' which caused my firestore channel to shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

run flutter clean in terminal to remove build artifacts and then rebuild your project using flutter build or flutter run .
this will work for me

Answer (score -1):

try to use strong network connection sometimes cause of this error is weak wifi connection