# I am getting this error often STREAM closed with status Unavailable

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
W/Firestore( 6377): (24.2.2) [WriteStream]: (de0ea67) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
W/DynamiteModule( 6377): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6377): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6377): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller( 6377): Failed to report request stats: reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
```

I am working on an Android application named cricket-info. Used Firestore database. When I run this application on an Android emulator (virtual device) it shows this warning and my data is not updated on firebase even taking more time to authenticate the user to the app. But whenever I run this app on a physical device my data gets updated and takes very less time to authenticate user...!

Code:

```
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

[image: Code]

Also tried reinstalling Android Studio and Flutter.

Comment: please post code

Comment: @SankethB.K Thank you for your reply!!. I have posted the code for adding the document

Comment: Code looks fine, i am not sure where you have defined _firestore variable

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem. Also same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73345658/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-backend-didnt-respond-within-10-second and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036076/firestore-stream-closed-with-status-unavailable-description-channel-shutdownnow This is a MAJOR BUG yet no one wants to fix it. I've resorted to using a physical android device for all development of flutter.